# grep command with regex issue

Tags: unix

file containing filelist and having one of the name as "abc_xyz1234.txt", while running

```
grep -E "abc_xyz????" <filename>
```

getting desired output where it shows that pattern is present in file but when i try

```
grep -E "abc_xyz????.txt" <filename>
```

doesn't show anything, can you please let me know what's wrong here,
TIA

Comment: Please show the contents of `<filename>` **in your question.** Probably you confused regular expressions with shell glob characters, aka wildcards. If you expect `?` to stand for any single character you would have to use `.` instead. To match a literal dot `.` you have to use `\.`. In this case you would have to use `grep -E "abc_xyz....\.txt" <filename>`. Depending on your needs you might have to anchor the search pattern to the beginning and/or end of line, e.g. `grep -E "^abc_xyz....\.txt$" <filename>`

Comment: In addition to some example contents of `<filename>`, show the desired output.

Comment: So content of file is abc_xyz1234.txt, i got to know that since using -E , grep is expecting the pattern to be in regex format, "?" interpreted correctly but ".(dot)" is actually part of filename not wildcard, but even if use grep -E "abc_xyz????\.txt" <filename> i am not getting any output ...(have used backslash)

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** and show a few lines from `<filename>` and the expected output there. Add requested information/clarification to the question, not in comments. **`abc_xyz????\.txt` is wrong.** This matches `abc_xy` followed by 0 or 1 `y`. It must be `abc_xyz....\.txt`. Please explain in your question what characters you want to match. If you want to match exactly 4 digits you could use `grep -E 'abc_xyz[0-9]{4}\.txt'` Option `-E` means **extended** regex in contrast to **basic** regex (the default). see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/grep.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse shell glob characters (wildcards) with a regular expression.

Assuming you have a file `abc_xyz1234.txt`, a shell command

```
echo abc_xyz????.txt
```

would show the file name (and other matching names). A question mark `?` matches any single character here.

In regular expressions, a question mark `?` can be appended to a pattern to indicate that the pattern should occur 0 or 1 times. Repeated question marks have the same result.
In regular expressions, to match any single character you have to use a dot `.`. If you want to match a literal dot you have to escape the dot with a preceding backslash `\.`.

To match the file name in a similar way with `grep` you would use one of these patterns

```
grep -E 'abc_xyz....\.txt' inputfile
grep -E 'abc_xyz.{4}\.txt' inputfile
```

or to make sure you don't get partial matches like `fooabc_xyz1234.txt` you can anchor the pattern to the beginneing and/or end of the line.

```
grep -E '^abc_xyz.{4}\.txt$' inputfile
```

**Explanation of the wrong pattern `abc_xyz????.txt`:**

- The character sequences `abc_xy` and `txt` stand for themselves.
- The `z` followed by 4 question marks `?` means the same as with a single question mark:

  - `z?` a literal `z` 0 or 1 times
  - `z??` (a literal `z` 0 or 1 times) 0 or 1 times
  - `z???` ((a literal `z` 0 or 1 times) 0 or 1 times) 0 or 1 times
  - ...
- The dot `.` matches any character.

This will **not** match your example file name `abc_xyz1234.txt`.

Examples for matching file names:

- `abc_xyz.txt`
- `abc_xy.txt`
- `abc_xyzAtxt`
- `abc_xy7txt`